# Using a case when result for comparison in another case when in NetSuite

Tags: search, formula, netsuite

I am trying to run an equation on a saved search in NetSuite that uses a formula, and a field.

I can run this and I get the correct value:

```
CASE WHEN {systemnotes.context}='UI' AND {systemnotes.field}='Date Closed' THEN {systemnotes.newvalue} END
```

And, this returns the correct value:

```
{startdate}
```

But, I can not figure out how to say that if the first case does not return a null value, and the second one is not null then give me the difference between the two.  I was trying something like this (in many different variations:

```
CASE WHEN [(CASE WHEN {systemnotes.context}='UI' AND {systemnotes.field}='Date Closed' THEN {systemnotes.newvalue} END) IS NOT NULL AND {startdate} IS NOT NULL] THEN
{CASE WHEN {systemnotes.context}='UI' AND {systemnotes.field}='Date Closed' THEN {systemnotes.newvalue} END)-{startdate}
```

END

Every time I run it I get invalid expression.  I've Googled around adn con not seem to find anything that discusses this type of operation, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula below worked for me.  I couldn't tell what recordtype you were running against so I just added a custom date field to the case record called `Test Date Field`. Just replace the field name with yours and it should work.

The key is that `{systemnotes.newvalue}` returns text so you need to wrap that result in `TO_DATE()` to convert it.  Then you can subtract `{startdate}` from it.

Your column type should be Formula(numeric).

```
case when 
(CASE WHEN {systemnotes.context}='UI' AND {systemnotes.field}='Test Date Field' THEN {systemnotes.newvalue} END is not null and {startdate} is not null)
then (TO_DATE(CASE WHEN {systemnotes.context}='UI' AND {systemnotes.field}='Test Date Field' THEN {systemnotes.newvalue} END) - {startdate}) END
```

Comment: Looks like this could be what I need.  Though I'm still getting errors.  To clear it up, These are the values from one of the records.  startdate =  2015-06-09 And closed date = 06/19/2015 14:12:11.  Looks like it is an issue of the timestamp structure.  Is there a way to rewrite that?  Also, are you pulling this from a resource online?  I'd love to read up about it.

Comment: I tried updating it to add TO_DATE around the startdate field.  the corrected the format of the startdate.  But, when I try to run it with both fields wrapped in TO_DATE, I get the same generic error.

Comment: One of the things I do when troubleshooting complex formulas in either NetSuite or Excel is to try to simplify the logic with substitution in Notepad or some other editor.  For example:  `zzz=CASE WHEN {sysetmnotes}......(some really long expression)` then I can work with something smaller like `CASE WHEN zzz IS NOT NULL AND {startdate} IS NOT NULL THEN TO_DATE(zzz) - {startdate} END`.  This helps me make sure that my logic and parens are all in the right place.  Then I just copy and paste my really long expression everywhere I see `zzz`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too.  My logic was correct.  Problem appears to be that NetSuite will not run a calculation on the "newvalue" field.  Below is the way we managed to get it to work.  I'm marking yours as a correct answer since it would have worked had NetSuite run calculations on that column.   CEIL(CASE WHEN {systemnotes.context} = 'UI' AND {systemnotes.field} LIKE '%Closed' THEN {systemnotes.date} END - {startdate})